# How to flatten out the concatenation of IEnumerables of IEnumerables

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, readonly, readonly-collection

I know there's a `LINQ` solution somewhere, I just can't see it. The situation I have is this: I have a `base class` (lets call it *B*, for now) that accepts a vararg and uses it to initialize a `readonly` field, which happens to be a `IReadonlyCollection` (lets call this field *List*).

I have two `derived classes` (lets call them *D1* and *D2*) that do the exact same thing with their vararg argument, passing it to the `base class` constructor, no problems there.

But I have a third `derived class` (lets call this one *D_1_and_2*), derived from the same `base class`, B, that accepts as parameters for its constructor 2 arrays, one of type `D1[]` and the other of type `D2[]`.

My problem is, somehow I have to concatenate all elements of the first parameter's (the `D1[]` parameter) `List` fields with each other and with all the elements of the second paramenter's `List` fields and pass the resulting array to the `base class` during construction. Bellow is an illustration of the problem in code.

```
public class CollectionElement
{

}

public class BaseClass
{
    public readonly IReadOnlyCollection<CollectionElement> TheCollection;

    public BaseClass(params CollectionElement[] arg)
    {
        TheCollection = Arrays.AsReadOnly(arg);
    }
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(params CollectionElement[] arg)
        :base(arg){}
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(params CollectionElement[] arg)
        :base(arg){}
}

public class DerivedClassA_Plus_B : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(DerivedClassA[] argA, DerivedClassB[] argB)
        :base(/*[don't know]*/){}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to project and then flatten the elements, and then [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) to join the two sequences together.

```
public class DerivedClassA_Plus_B : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(DerivedClassA[] argA, DerivedClassB[] argB)
        :base(Combine(argA, argB)) { }

    private static CollectionElement[] Combine(DerivedClassA[] argA, DerivedClassB[] argB)
    {
        var a = argA.SelectMany(x => x.TheCollection);
        var b = argB.SelectMany(x => x.TheCollection);
        return a.Concat(b).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks!